# How can I integrate Google Maps APIs inside an Angular 2 component

Tags: google-maps, angular, angular2-template

I have an Angular 2 component that is defined in the file comp.ts in this way like this:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@component({
    selector:'my-comp',
    templateUrl:'comp.html'
})

export class MyComp{
    constructor(){
    }
}
```

Because I want the component to show a google map, I have inserted in the file comp.html the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
    zoom:5,
    mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

This code has been copied from this link http://www.w3schools.com/googleAPI/google_maps_basic.asp. The problem is that the component doesn't show the map. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have found a solution. First of all, the following line:

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]"></script>
```

must be inserted in the index.html file. The code which creates the map must be inserted in the comp.ts file. In particular, it must be inserted in a special method, namely "ngOnInit", which can be positioned after the constructor of the class. This is comp.ts:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';

declare const google: any;

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl:'appHtml/app.html',
    styleUrls: ['css/app.css']
})

export class AppMainComponent {
    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit() {
        let mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        let map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"), mapProp);
    }
}
```

Finally, the div with id "googleMap", which is going to contain the google map, must be inserted in the comp.html file, which will look like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should put the element you want your map displayed in into your component's html template. Just for clarification. You usually don't have body tags in your template.

Comment: This kind of solution also works on Angular 5.x. Great answer, thanks! If you use this in that version, you might need `npm install @types/googlemaps --save`.

Comment: @tkhm i am getting `google is not defined` in console

Comment: Did you import types? In other words,  did you add `import { } from @types/googlemaps` on your ts file ?

Answer (score 23):

Yeah, you could do so. But there would be an error in typescript compiler, so don't forget to implicitly declare google variable.

```
declare var google: any;
```

add this directive right after component import.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
declare var google: any;

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit() {
    var mapProp = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742, -0.120850),
            zoom: 5,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), mapProp);
  }
}
```

Comment: The ngOnInit helped me resolve a getElementById problem i had thanks ! as of the google var declaration, i suggest using [gmaps typings] (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/googlemaps/google.maps.d.ts) it helps really well

Comment: @youssef I am getting `google is not defined` in console

Comment: @Arbaaz i guess the google maps JS is not properly imported in your app, can you provide a GIST/simple code of your app ?

Answer (score -5):

Use angular2-google-maps: https://angular-maps.com/

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';

import { AgmCoreModule } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
    styles: [`
        .sebm-google-map-container {
            height: 300px;
        }
    `],
  template: `
        <sebm-google-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></sebm-google-map>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
  lat: number = 51.678418;
  lng: number = 7.809007;
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: 'YOUR_GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY'
    })
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```