# Google Places API - Nearby search (Ionic 2)

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, google-places-api

I have currently integrated the Google maps api in my app and want to include google places as well (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search). I have got as far as the Geolocation but from then on I am kinda lost. I want to do a nearby search for "supermarkets" but I am struggling converting it into Typescript/angular.

The code I currently have that enables geolocation is

loadMap(){

```
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

  let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

  let mapOptions = {
    center: latLng,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }

  this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);

 }, (err) => {
   console.log(err);
 }); 
}

addMarker(){

 let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   map: this.map,
   animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
   position: this.map.getCenter()
 });

 let content = "<h4>You are here!</h4>";          

 this.addInfoWindow(marker, content);

}

addInfoWindow(marker, content){

 let infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
   content: content
 });

 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', () => {
   infoWindow.open(this.map, marker);
 });
}
```

If someone could help me integrate/convert the places api into my current code that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I integrate Google Maps APIs inside an Angular 2 component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326572/how-can-i-integrate-google-maps-apis-inside-an-angular-2-component)

Comment: Not a duplicate as Google maps api is working fine for me, I want the addition of google places

Answer (score 0):

I think this article will help you.
https://ampersandacademy.com/tutorials/ionic-framework-version-2/google-map-places-search-api-example.

It uses the typescript google map library.

```
 npm install @types/googlemaps --save-dev
```

To search Location use

```
new google.maps.places.AutocompleteService();
```