# how to use/integrate google maps apis in angular 4

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-maps-markers

```
how to use google maps apis in angular 4.
```

I am trying to use google maps.
    gave reference to **google maps api** with the key.
    but not able to use it.
    while integrating it . got the error google is not defined and to resolve i declared var google:any 
    error got resolved but it is not building the map and now i am getting 
    "Cannot read property 'firstChild' of null"

Comment: Have a go with this: https://angular-maps.com/

Comment: Have a look at the answers for this question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326572/how-can-i-integrate-google-maps-apis-inside-an-angular-2-component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326572/how-can-i-integrate-google-maps-apis-inside-an-angular-2-component)

Answer (score 2):

**You can try this:**

**Step 1:** `npm install @types/googlemaps --save`

**Step 2** : Add below line into your **`index.html`** with **correct google API key** ( Don't forget it )

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
async defer></script>
```

**Step 3**: Add below line to your html where you want to add google map

```
<div #googleMap style=”width:300%;height:300px”></div>
```

**Step 4:** Now you add below code into your angular component

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { } from '@types/googlemaps';

@Component({
  selector: 'map-component',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})

export class MapComponent {
  @ViewChild('googleMap') gmapElement: any;
  map: google.maps.Map;

  ngOnInit() {
    var mapProp = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(28.4595, 77.0266),
      zoom: 14,
      // mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
      // mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
      // mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
    };

    this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.gmapElement.nativeElement, mapProp);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: mapProp.center });
    marker.setMap(this.map);

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: "Hey, We are here"
    });

    infowindow.open(this.map, marker);
  }
}
```

**Congratulations !!!**

**Here is the snapshot what you did.**

[image: Google map]