# using third party library in angular

Tags: angular

How can i use third party library in angular 4? 
Normally i used code below :

```js
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap CDN Simple Example</title>
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> Bootstrap CDN Simple Complete HTML Example</h1>    
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve that.

You can simply add the `<script>` to your `index.html` file, like you described above and then access it through `declare var google: any;` (or whatever name your library has).

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37326572/how-can-i-integrate-google-maps-apis-inside-an-angular-2-component#answer-38812793) an example for using google maps in angular.

Or you can install the library from npm (with the accoriding types) and simply import it like this:

`import * as _ from "lodash";`

[Here's](https://alligator.io/angular/third-party-libraries-angular/) an example for this approach.